# How do I install Brother QL-700 label printer drivers in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, printing, brother

I recently purchased a **Brother QL-700** label printer for printing address labels in Ubuntu 12.04. The [Brother website](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_esp1.html) lists Linux drivers, specifically for Ubuntu 8.04+. I have installed the driver and the printer shows up in **System Settings** → **Printers**, but the status there is stuck at "Processing - Waiting for printer to become available" and I'm unable to use the printer.

In case anyone's wondering, I have indeed:

- Powered it on,
- Connected it via USB,
- Installed both the lpr and cupswrapper drivers listed, and
- Followed the directions on Brother's site.

I'm kind of at a loss. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Running Ubuntu 13.10 amd64 I just followed the instrunctions on http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_esp1.html and it just works.

*Caveat*: turn off "Editor Lite" on the printer (hold little button on front until LED turns off) otherwise the printer will not be accssible to CUPS.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the editor lite! Unfortunately, I'm still stuck. :(

Comment: I am on centos and was stuck on the brother printer until I pressed on the Editor lite :D Thanks for the tip, for me it worked great (note: I had already installed the drivers available at the vendors website)

Comment: The link is dead. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my friend :D

http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public/eu/eu_ot/en/dlf/download_index.html?reg=eu&c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=lpql700euk&dlid=&flang=English&os=130&type2=-1

download the driver and ist done! good luck

Comment: "download the driver and ist done", what about installing the driver? You could elaborate your answer.

Comment: That didn't work; as I noted in the question, I downloaded and installed the drivers from the Brother site without success.